# Merge overlapping rasters using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I have around 211 rasters, one for each area of the world. The gdalinfo for one of them is below. They are all the same except for the area of concern. Values are always between 1-6.

[image]

I would like to merge them into one giant raster for the world. I have managed to successfully do this by first building a VRT, and then writing the VRT to a single file:

```
gdalbuildvrt.exe -b 1 -q -input_file_list my_files.txt global_file.vrt

gdal_translate.exe -q -co PREDICTOR=2 -co COMPRESS=LZW -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS global_file.vrt global_file.tif
```

The result was around 15GB in size.

However my issue is that there are often areas where each country overlap. In those cases I need to take the max raster/pixel value. But gdal_translate does not do that, it just takes the last value that was written.

I read about the PixelFunction, (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350233/how-can-i-modify-a-vrtrasterband-sub-class-etc-from-python) and tried to implement it, but I kept getting memory issues.

Does anyone have any ideas on a memory-safe way to combine a large list of rasters and to take the maximum value where they overlap? If the best way is the PixelFunction then let me know and I will provide more details about the errors.

Thanks, James

Comment: Use `gdalwarp` to expand each raster to the final global extent. Loop over the rasters and run `gdal_calc.py` with `--calc="fmax(A,B)"` where A is the current raster and B is the stored result of the last calc. You may have to do something about ignoring nodata values.

Comment: The PixelFunction should be the right way to do it, I am afraid that if you ran into memory problems with a PixelFunction, so you will with `gdal_calc.py` too. What format is the input data in? If it is GeoTiff, is it tiled and what is the block size?

Comment: Unrelated but I would start by making your inputs also tiled, that works a lot better in combination with VRT's that have a hard coded blocksize of 128x128. Regarding the overlap, using the pixel function on the VRT might save you the intermediate global files.

Comment: @mmomtchev -- The input data is GeoTiff. I do not think that it is tiled at all, though I'm not very familiar with it. If you see the output of gdalinfo above, I think the section which says Block = 8100x1 .

Comment: Well, do you understand what does this mean? The default output block is 256x256 - you need to store in memory 256 blocks of your 1 line blocks to read it - multiplied by 211 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing your output block size, use `BLOCKXSIZE=128` and `BLOCKYSIZE=128`:

```
gdal_translate.exe -q -co PREDICTOR=2 -co COMPRESS=LZW -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=128 -co BLOCKYSIZE=128 -co TILED=YES -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS global_file.vrt global_file.tif
```

This will require significantly less memory.

If this doesn't work, your next option would be to convert all of your input files to 128x128 tiled geotiffs. Alas, in GDAL <3.7 you can't change the block size of the VRT driver, it is something that is coming in 3.7.

Comment: I should use this in combination with the pixel function right? I'll give it a try